# How to add multiple metaentries in orchard?

Tags: tags, content-management-system, orchardcms, meta

I need to add two meta tags. I have this:

```html
        MetaEntry FBphoto = new MetaEntry();
    FBfoto.AddAttribute("property", "og:image");
    FBfoto.AddAttribute("content", "image.jpg");
    SetMeta(FBphoto);

    MetaEntry FBdescription = new MetaEntry();
    FBdescription.AddAttribute("property", "og:description");
    FBdescription.AddAttribute("content", "Some description");
    SetMeta(FBdescription);
```

Unfortunatelly SetMeta adds only second metaentry (FBdescription). How can I achieve to add them both? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is because if you look in `ResourceManager.SetMeta` there's the following code

```
public void SetMeta(MetaEntry meta) {
if (meta == null) {
    return;
}

var index = meta.Name ?? meta.HttpEquiv ?? "charset";

_metas[index] = meta;
```

}

Therefore your second call to the method is overwriting the entry from the first (the one with the key "charset").

If you look at a module called [Social Media Tags](https://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Om.Orchard.SocialMetaTags) on the Orchard Gallery and the source on [GitHub](https://github.com/bhavinbdoshi/Om.Orchard.SocialMetaTags) they are adding the tags in the [driver](https://github.com/bhavinbdoshi/Om.Orchard.SocialMetaTags/blob/master/Drivers/OpenGraphMetaTagsPartDriver.cs) building up the meta in a [helper class](https://github.com/bhavinbdoshi/Om.Orchard.SocialMetaTags/blob/master/Helpers/SocialMetaTagsHelpers.cs)

In that code, they are just using the key as the property name without the colon so your code would become

```
MetaEntry FBphoto = new MetaEntry();
FBphoto.Name = "ogimage";
FBphoto.AddAttribute("property", "og:image");
FBphoto.AddAttribute("content", "image.jpg");
SetMeta(FBphoto);

MetaEntry FBdescription = new MetaEntry();
FBdescription.Name = "ogdescription";
FBdescription.AddAttribute("property", "og:description");
FBdescription.AddAttribute("content", "Some description");
SetMeta(FBdescription);
```

which does get both the tags on the page. I don't think there's any harm in having the name attibutes, they just aren't required, but you'd need to confirm this.